# How could I use the same button to achieve the fadeOut() and fadeIn()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question just like my title.
I want to fadeOut a pic when I click the button, and I want to fadeIn the pic again when I click the same button again.

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    if($("#div1").display == 1){       // Your comparison was wrong, you assigned the value 1 to  $("#div1").display
        $("#div1").fadeOut(1000,"easeOutBounce",function(){         
            alert("Fade Out");
        });
    }
    else{
        $("#div1").fadeIn({
            duration: 1000,
            easing: "easeOutBounce",
            complete: function(){
                alert("Fade In");
            }
        });
    }
})
```

My result is when I finished my fadeOut(), it would pop up "Fade Out".
When I clicked button again, it would show the "Fade Out" again.
It did not run the else part. 
It did not fadeIn() and show "Fade In".
How could I achieve it?

Comment: Are you familiar with toggle? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: moreover you have `$("#div1").display = 1` which I don't know what it is but should be `$("#div1").display == 1`

Comment: Just as @GeorgeBailey said, check your comparison operator inside of the if-statement https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: Thank you both, but when I change to "==" it is not working...
but I solved it by fadeToggle().

Comment: As all the answer best solution is to use fadeToggle but just to find out what went wrong in your code, I think the css property you should refer is opacity

Answer (score 3):

You have an assignment in your if

```
 if($("#div1").display = 1){
                       ^^^
```

This would always return true. Moreover, I don't know if this is the correct way to check if something is active on DOM, you normally do this with

`$(element).is(":visible");`

And your code can be reduced to just one like

You just need a [**`fadeToggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) here. That'll do that

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){

   $("#t").fadeToggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t">This is a div</div>

<button id="btn">BTN</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you using [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) instead.

fadeToggle( [duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
   $('#div1').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
})
```

```css
#div1 {width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>

<br />

<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

following is an [example](https://codepen.io/anilnamde/pen/VxGNLN) of toggle fade which as it says helps you toggle fade effect

```
// HTML
<button > toggle</button>
<img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt=""
/>

// JS
$('button').click(()=>{
  $( "img" ).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve toggle functionality you can use the fadeToggle() method : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadetoggle.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `fadeToggle()` jquery method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Click</button><br><br>

<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is the same effect using just javascript and CSS:

```js
var squareDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var toggleFadeButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-fade')[0];

function toggleFade() {
    squareDiv.classList.toggle('fade');
}

toggleFadeButton.addEventListener('click', toggleFade, false);
```

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 12px 12px 0;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
vertical-align: bottom;
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 1.2s linear;
}

div.fade {
opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<button type="button" class="toggle-fade">Toggle Fade</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn").click(function(){

    if($("#div1").css('display') == 'block'){
      $("#div1").fadeOut(1000,"linear",function(){         
            alert("Fade Out");
        });
    }
    else{
        $("#div1").fadeIn({
            duration: 1000,
            easing: "linear",
            complete: function(){
                alert("Fade In");
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Will (possibly...) +1 if you add a description of what you've changed/why.

Comment: See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: Sorry sir @freedomn-m 

In this scenario i never seen $("#div1").display == 1, May be this is possible, but i don't no more about that.
I think, here is condition to find div is hide or show and task is perform on the basis of its display property.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer - just need the comment you made in the description to show what you've changed in the code.   The meta link explains it more - in summary:  *While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.*